# npm runs GET for downloaded packages during all installations

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

Whenever I try to install a node package using npm it runs the following commands:

```
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.1.10.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler/-/domhandler-2.2.0.tgz
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima/-/esprima-1.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/esprima/-/esprima-1.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/punycode/-/punycode-1.2.3.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/0.0.2
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/punycode/-/punycode-1.2.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/0.0.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/-/debuglog-0.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/-/debuglog-0.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/argparse/-/argparse-0.1.15.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/argparse/-/argparse-0.1.15.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
...
```

I know that these are dependencies for the package, but for example whereas the `cryptiles` package is installed now, next time when I want to install another package which depends on `cryptiles` npm again runs this command:

```
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

npm works this way by design.

Because `npm` installs package locally, and not globally you can end up with multiple version of the `cryptiles` package, because your application depends on 0.2.x and another package depends on 0.1.x for instance.

You can read the first item (*Handle multiple versions of the same thing at the same time*) of [this blog post](http://blog.izs.me/post/1675072029/10-cool-things-you-probably-didnt-realize-npm-could-do), written by the creator of `npm` to understand this better.